# Эмитация сокет запросов

Tags: сокет, websocket

Если с http протоколом все просто и есть утилита postman для эмитирования запросов с любыми настройками. Есть ли какой нибудь подобный аналог утилиты для веб сокетов? Может я конечно не прав и этот инструмент не нужен. На первый взгляд кажется полезным. Просветите по поводу этого вопроса, пожалуйста )

Comment: причем тут `java`?

Comment: К чему вопрос? ЯП не имеет значения. Могу хоть С++ указать. Вопрос как много людей увидят запрос в метках по сокетам, куда никто не заходит.

Comment: тогда это уже манипуляция. хотите обратить внимание на вопрос - сделайте конкурс

Comment: В ответах на запрос [websocket test](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=780&ei=AmSBXMPMEeuSmwXp1bf4AQ&q=websocket+test+&oq=websocket+test+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0j0i20i263j0j0i203j0j0i203j0l2j0i203.103327.103327..105773...0.0..0.62.62.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.f_5sEcnPDSA) ничего подходящего нет?

Comment: да точно. Как я не догадался))) Спасибо, то что нужно.